# How do I pass a model from controller to another controller in asp .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core

Now I am following the tutorial. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model
And I am curious about how do I pass DBcontexts from controller to another controller  or read db datas.
I tried to use WebMatrix but VS gives me message that It is not compatible with core.

Comment: Perhaps you should wait until you get to the section on dependency injection before you start passing a DBContext around. It is right there on the same page you linked to.

Comment: Yea, better you read the whole documentation and also about how HTTP works in general, before starting to code. HTTP is a stateless protocol (state is not persisted between requests, take off sessions which still requires the client to send a cookie or something identifying it), each request results in one call to a specific controller. As such you don't pass something from one controller to another. You pass response to the client (browser) and browser passes it to a new controller. It's different than Desktop/Console applications

Comment: Oh thanks you both!!I think I really should take time and read whole docs.

Comment: Or aspnetquickstart.com